# Raspberry Pi and Touchscreen (Digiziter)

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

Is it possible to connect via GPIO Touchscreen like this 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-7-SG5984-FPC-V1-1-SG5984-SG5984-FPC-V1-1-SG5984-FPC-Touchscreen-Capacitive-Digiziter/32663044297.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10091_10090_10088_10089,searchweb201603_1&btsid=74329f22-4168-4468-bf07-f924bbaf814a 
to RPI 3? What drivers should I use for it?

Yeah, I know, that there are HDMI touchscreens, but they are very expensive for me and I am looking for cheap alternatives, like Touchscreen, link I provided above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the touch only, without the needed controller. One *could* employ GPIOs for this but there are simply too many needed, much more than the Raspberry has, and building an interface circuit would cost more than using a touch with an integrated controller.

Those come in USB or I2C flavor. USB ones usually work out of the box because they conform to the USB-HID specification. Most I2C ones need a special driver, though I2C-HID also exists.

When you really need it cheap, look for a *resistive* (foil) touch instead. 15" ones cost about $20 for a single piece incl. controller. No multi-touch then, of course.